# Backup data for later restore (save previous values)

Tags: excel, vba, backup

I am trying to figure out a way to backup data to recover it when I need it. During the UserForm initialization I am doing

```
'Save Backup
Worksheets("Machine Format").Cells(ActiveCell.Column).EntireColumn.copy
```

which would be preferred if it's not the entire column but only rows with data, but I don't know how to combine this code with

```
Dim LastRow As Long

LastRow = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```

Everything I could think of didn't work, however when I try to paste previously copied data with

```
'Paste Backup
ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Machine Format").Cells(ActiveCell.Column)
```

it doesn't paste it and shows no error either. I'm not even sure if the concept of backing up data like this is an optimal or good idea.

Could someone help me, please, in solving this issue? The reason why I even need this is because I have a userform that modifies data realtime and upon closing the userform via X button I need it to cancel all the changes and I figure that I could copy the data upon userform initialization and then paste it back in if userform was closed via x button.

Comment: Maybe this is an option for you: Make a copy of the entire sheet to `Machine Format Backup` and if you need to use the backup delete `Machine Format` and rename `Machine Format Backup` to `Machine Format`.

Comment: Maybe there's a way to store that data in an array on computer memory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save the values in an array

```
Dim BackupArray() As Variant
BackupArray = Worksheets("Machine Format").UsedRange.Value
```

And if you have to return them you can use

```
Worksheets("Machine Format").Cells(row, column).Value = BackupArray(row, column)
```

to return specific values from the backup, or revert the entire values at once:

```
Worksheets("Machine Format").UsedRange.Value = BackupArray
```

Note that this works only on changed values. If new values were added and you want to remove them too you need to clear the contents of all cells first and revert to the original range:

```
Dim OriginalDataRange As Range
Set OriginalDataRange = Worksheets("Machine Format").UsedRange

Dim BackupArray() As Variant
BackupArray = OriginalDataRange.Value

' do your changes here

' revert entire backup
Worksheets("Machine Format").UsedRange.ClearContents  'remove changed data including new added data
OriginalDataRange.Value = BackupArray  ' revert old tata
```

Make `BackupArray` a public variable if creating the backup and restoring does not happen in the same procedure.

Note that if you accidentally stop the entirve VBA run eg. by using the `End` statement (do not mix up with `End Sub`!) then the backup data is lost. It only persists during the runtime of VBA (or better the lifetime of the variable `BackupArray`).

Comment: Not sure where do I write those bits.

Comment: The backup part needs to be before your userform makes changes to the data, and the reverting part if the user presses the cancel button or something. That's something we actually cannot tell you, it is on you to know where you want it. I can just answer your question how to make a backup and how to revert it, but I cannot tell you how to organize your project.

Comment: Yeah I have  Dim BackupArray() As Variant
BackupArray = Worksheets("Machine Format").UsedRange.Value as one of the first things on userform initialization and  Worksheets("Machine Format").UsedRange.Value = BackupArray upon clicking X button and no reverting occurs

Comment: Make sure you use `Option Explicit` and make sure you declare `BackupArray` as a global variable.

Comment: The code is in the same module of the userform

Comment: Still you need to do what I wrote in my last comment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232500/discussion-between-eduards-and-p).

Comment: Problem with this solution is that I have some formulas and connected data from another userform or sheet and that link breaks

Comment: Well if you have formulas, you have probably only the option not to edit your sheet directly with the userform. Instead load the data into the textboxes for example and only write it back to the sheet with the save button. So the data get's not changed in case you don't press save. • I think you are up the wrong tree with your backup idea.

Answer (score 1):

### Backup Column Data

```vb
Option Explicit

Private bData As Variant ' Array
Private brg As Range ' Column Range (object)

Sub UsageExample()

    ' Some code...
    backupData
    ' some more code...
    
    If Something Then
        ' Whatever...
    Else
        retrieveData
    End If
    
End Sub

Sub backupData()
        
    Const wsName As String = "Machine Format"
    Const First As Long = 2
    Const lrCol As String = "B"
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    With wb.Worksheets(wsName)
        .Activate
        If TypeName(Selection) = "Range" Then
            ' Create a reference to the column range.
            Dim Last As Long: Last = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            Dim cCol As Long: cCol = Selection.Cells(1).Column
            Set brg = .Columns(cCol).Rows(First & ":" & Last)
            ' Write the values from the column range to an array.
            If brg.Cells.Count = 1 Then
                ReDim bData(1 To 1, 1 To 1): bData(1, 1) = brg.Value
            Else
                bData = brg.Value
            End If
        'Else
            ' No range selected.
        End If
    End With

End Sub

Sub retrieveData()

    If Not brg Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print brg.Address
        Debug.Print UBound(bData, 1), UBound(bData, 2)
        ' Write data back to range.
        brg.Value = bData
    Else
        Debug.Print "No range."
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Could you please explain how to use this?

Comment: How I understood your question: `Some code` is the code you're not showing. Then you want to backup a column of data which the procedure `backupData` does. Now, you want to do something to the data in this column (`some more code` (not showing)) and if everything is Ok, your good (`Whatever`), but if something is wrong you want to kind of `undo` these operations and get the data to the previous state which the `retrieveData` procedure does. Note that `bData` and `brg` are available to all procedures in this module. If you could post the rest of the code, I may be able to better explain it.